# Truncated BigQuery error message on "No matching signature"

Tags: error-handling, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

While integrating a UDF for use in a query, it's common to get a `No matching signature` error. These errors are very informative when the function signature is short. However when the function signature is long, such as in a case where it's a JS UDF receiving and returning complex structs, the error message is truncated and becomes useless.

For example:

```
No matching signature for function f for argument types: STRUCT<docGroup FLOAT64, docNum FLOAT64, docDate DATE, ...>.
Supported signature: f(STRUCT<docGroup FLOAT64, docNum FLOAT64, docDate DATE, ...>) at [202:8]
```

The actual mismatch is hiding somewhere in the truncated arguments!

Running `bq show -j <jobid>` also shows the message with a truncated list of arguments.

Is there any way of getting the full error message, or otherwise figuring out what's wrong, without having to take my SQL apart into pieces?

Comment: Running into the same issue, but for better answers it might be helpful to add a toy reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bq show --format=prettyjson -j <jobid>` 
The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#viewing_information_about_jobs:) says that this is the syntax for seeing the job's complete information:

> To see full job details, enter:
>
> bq show --format=prettyjson -j
>   myproject:US.bquijob_123x456_789y123z456c

Comment: Doesn't help.

This would have helped if the problem was that the error message had the full argument list, but then had been truncated somewhere along the way to my console.

But actually the problem is deeper than that - the error message arrives in its entirety, but when putting it together in the first place, someone took the trouble to truncate the arguments list. This makes the error message nice&short, but completely useless for non-trivial use cases.

Comment: Can you share an example of the UDF you're using? I'd like to try reproducing the issue here